# Sessions per Hour and Minute: SQL - BigQuery / GA360

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to measure the impact of TV-Advertising on website sessions and transactions. 
Therefore, I need all (new) sessions per hour and minute to compare these with the TV airing time. I thought about selecting the hits.hitnumber and filter it by all values that equal 1 (=first hit). However, I get too little sessions, around one third of what GA displays.
Any help is appreciated!

```
SELECT
date,
hits.hour, 
hits.minute,
hits.hitNumber,
totals.transactions,
hits.item.productName,
FROM [XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20180221] 
WHERE hits.hitNumber =1
GROUP BY date, hits.hour, hits.minute, hits.hitNumber ,totals.transactions, hits.item.productName
```

Comment: Some sample data, or a minimal version of it, would help here.  If your query isn't returning what you expect, then either its logic is wrong, or the data has a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be several sessions with the same values of the fields you are grouping by, so you should add session identifiers (in BQ, this is the combination of fullVisitorId and visitId) at least in the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitId,
  date,
  hits.hour, 
  hits.minute,
  hits.hitNumber,
  totals.transactions,
  hits.item.productName,
FROM [XXXXXXXX.ga_sessions_20180221] 
WHERE hits.hitNumber =1
GROUP BY 
  fullVisitorId, visitId, date, hits.hour, hits.minute, hits.hitNumber,
  totals.transactions, hits.item.productName
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!